# How to cache database reads in Azure roles?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, caching, azure

In my Azure role I have a lot of entities that have to be stored in an SQL Azure database. Currently whenever I need to read an entity I just run an SQL Azure query.

I suspect it will soon become a bottleneck so I have to implement some sort of caching - some memory structure that reads data on first access and then stores it for some period of time and returns cached data on subsequent reads. Crafting such structure should not be hard, I'm sure I can find code readily available.

The problem is what do I do with writes from several instances? For example, instance 1 reads the data and caches it, instance 2 changes the database. Unless instance 1 knows it has to reread the database and actually rereads the database it works with the wrong data. I have no idea of how to do that easily.

Is there a simple way to keep caches of different instances coherent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where distributed caching comee into play, and on Azure this generally means [Windows Azure AppFabric Caching](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/caching/)

The idea behind distributed caching is that the cache is centralized, and potentially distributed over several servers (for efficiency), that way a request for data does not have to go to the database, which is usually relatively expensive in terms of performance, but equally, that data does not have to be cached locally in each process.

Whilst obviously not as efficient as in-proc caching, distributed caching has several benefits -

1. It does prevent multiple calls to underlying source
2. With the cache out of process (and, in fact, on a different server) it reduced the pressure on local memory
3. Clients benefit from each other's fetches - i.e. if one client brings data into the cache, security settings permitting, other client's now have access to this information so the utilisation of the cache can be greater

This also means that clients with updated knowledge of 'the truth' can update the cache or indeed invalidate it, which would immediately benefit all other clients sharing the same cache.

Also - being a distributed model - the cache farm can be expanded to cater for many requests, although on Azure - as the cache is offered as a service, this is something the platform takes care of rather than the owner, which is one of the big benefits of PaaS and Windows Azure
    information to the cache

Answer (score 1):

You can use AppFabric caching as Yossi said, but you can also use [Memcached](http://www.davidaiken.com/2011/01/11/windows-azure-memcached-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Azure AppFabric caching and you want the data to be consistent you might want to turn off local caching.

The downside is that if you're pulling out more than a couple of items from the cache per request this is going to be a major bottleneck. You can try and get around this by combining your cached objects into one big object.

I [posted a question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/1e75a570-9c60-4e8a-8eba-12c81effdee8) that touches on this on the Microsoft forum, and the answer for now is stale data is just something to live with if local caching is required.

On a side note, if local caching is required and you're using a web role, plain old ASP.Net caching might be a better option, and doesn't come with a separate charge.